# HttpOnly cookies not sent by request

Tags: java, angular, cookies, jwt, cookie-httponly

I want to use `HttpOnly` cookies and I set it in Java as follows:

```
...

Cookie accessTokenCookie = new Cookie("token", userToken);
accessTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
accessTokenCookie.setSecure(true);
accessTokenCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(accessTokenCookie);
Cookie refreshTokenCookie = new Cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken);
refreshTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
refreshTokenCookie.setSecure(true);
refreshTokenCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie);

...
```

I got the client side the response with the cookies, but when I send the next request I do not have the cookies on the request. Maybe I miss something, but as I understood, these `HttpOnly` cookies has to be sent by the browser back on every request (JavaScript does not have access to those cookies) coming to the defined path.

I have the following Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,hu;q=0.6,ro;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
Authorization:Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:35
content-type:text/plain
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

and the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Date, Link, Server, X-Application-Context, X-Total-Count
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:482
Content-Type:application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 03 Feb 2017 13:11:29 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:token=eyJhbGciO;Max-Age=10000;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:refreshToken=eyJhb8w;Max-Age=10000;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Vary:Origin
```

Also in the client side I use `withCredentials: true` in Angular2 and `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` as request header.

And it is Cross Domain.

Comment: Hi !! I have faced a same issue. When I removed HTTP only flag then it works. Have you found any other work around ?

Comment: By removing the Secure flag from cookies, resolved the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are correct having the cookie your browser should send the cookie automatically while it is not expired and the httpOnly flag means it cannot be accessed or manipulated via JavaScript.

However

You need to ensure that the cookie you are sending is not cross domain, if you require it cross domain you will need to handle it differently.

Comment: Yes it's a cross domain cookie, how do I have to handle it?

Comment: Personally for your situation I would use JWT and headers but if you must use cross domain cookies try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: by removing the `Secure` flag from cookies, resolved the problem